# Extra list item bullet when using HTML and attributedText in UITextView

Tags: swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

We have an issue where UITextView displays bullets that do not exist in the HTML used for its attributedText. This happens when there is more than 1 nested list and other text content.

This displays correctly:

```
Heading 1
<ul>
    <li>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </li>
</ul>
        
Heading 2
<ul>
    <li>
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </li>
    <li>
        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

This displays with a bullet on Heading 2 as if it was a list item:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Heading 1
        <ul>
            <li>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </li>
        </ul>
        
        Heading 2
        <ul>
            <li>
                Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </li>
            <li>
                Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Any suggestions? Using a WKWebView works correctly, but some of these UITextViews are in tables and we don't want to tackle the row height issue when using a web view.